# How to clone a git project from Amazon EC2 to my local system?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm new to Amazon AWS and mostly use Heroku so would really appreciate any help here. I'm trying to clone a project from AWS. I'm running a command like this on bash :

git clone ssh://prajwal@ec2-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX.compute-1.amazonaws.com/home/prajwal/gitprojects/projectname

I have also been given the login credentials (a password) but just running the command above logs the following error:

Connection timed out
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Should I setup an SSH key for AWS? I just created my AWS account and went to the console but got overwhelmed. I dont want to host this project or anything, just clone it to my local system and that would enough.

Please help!

Comment: Did you setup a [git server](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) on your EC2?

Comment: Please follow this link https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/userguide/how-to-connect.html

Comment: @LawakushKurmi, thanks for sharing this particular doc, looks pretty straight forward to me and will follow along.

Comment: @QuentinRevel, I had not, I just felt overwhelmed and thought I'd stack overflow this as I had no clue coming from Heroku background. But the user guide Lawakush shared will help I suppose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps mentioned in the user guide Lawakush Kurmi shared and setup my SSH keys on AWS.